# Angular X-Editable - additional parameters to onbeforesave

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I am using angular-xeditable to edit a table value inline and want to save that value in the database once the input is blurred. What I want to do is call the save function using the "onbeforesave" attribute.

The problem is the function takes only the changed value as parameter. I also need the id of the  tag on which xeditable is applied.

So how can I pass a reference to the DOM element (best option) or just the element id (will suffice in this case).

Many thanks!

Comment: As a temporary solution I added "this" as parameter to the function, save($data, this), and then I access it using el.$editable.elem[0].id where function save(data, el). But there has to be a better way to do this ...

Comment: on your ng-repeat on front end, on your "onBeforeSave" attribute you can pass the $index so it will be like onBeforesave="myFUnction($index)" and then use the index in targeting the element of array to alter values. so if your front end ng-repeat uses $scope.items, you will use the index to target $scope.items[index] and then you can take all the data on this index and pass data to server to do some database updates.

Comment: Thanks, Darryl. You can post that as a response and I will accept it.

Comment: I re-posted my comment as a response already. Glad that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your `ng-repeat` on front end, on your "onBeforeSave" attribute you can pass the `$index` so it will be like `onBeforesave="myFUnction($index)"` and then use the index in targeting the element of array to alter values. so if your front end `ng-repeat` uses `$scope.items`, you will use the index to target `$scope.items[index]` and then you can take all the data on this index and pass data to server to do some database updates.

Comment: But $scope.items does not contain the updated value of $data with onBeforeSave. How do you get both the updated value, and the item or index to the item?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you can pass the repeated object, it can help when you'll try to figure out the object from that index, 
As explained here :

[How to use Angular-Xeditable's onBeforeSave / onAfterSave methods with more than $data as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418753/how-to-use-angular-xeditables-onbeforesave-onaftersave-methods-with-more-than)

```
<div ng-repeat="p in people">
    <a href="#" editable-text="p.name" onaftersave="updatePerson(p)">{{p.name}}</a>
</div>
```

You'd then have the following code in your controller:

```
$scope.updatePerson = function(person) {
    var ret = PersonService.save(person); // or whatever save mechanism you use
    // You need to return a error string if save fails, true otherwise
    if (ret !== null) {  // You have to make sure this logic works for your save service
        return ret;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

I prefer this solution because its avoiding index + filtering problems 
as explained here:
http://codeutopia.net/blog/2014/11/10/angularjs-best-practices-avoid-using-ng-repeats-index/