# Angularjs - X-Editable: $data in onAfterSave($data)

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, x-editable, multiple-select, multipleselection

What does the $data stores? does it store the object selected in my ng-options? Here's my markup:

```
<span editable-select="item.myDropdown" e-multiple e-ng-options="rol as rol.roleName for rol in myCtrl.roles" onaftersave="showUsers.save($data)" ng-model="myRole.roleSelected"></span>
```

Because I have a function on my script where it receives the $data as parameter. Here's my sample code:

```
$scope.save = function (data) { //data = $data
    var savedRole = data;       //data here is a JSON object
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Angular-Xeditable docs don't make it quite clear, but it appears that $data (and $index) are just injected values and that you can pass pretty much anything you want to the save/validate methods." -[Michael Oryl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418753/how-to-use-angular-xeditables-onbeforesave-onaftersave-methods-with-more-than)